# jQuery bind click *ANYTHING* but *ELEMENT*

Tags: jquery, click

Say there are some elements floating around, and I'm trying to do some when I click ANYTHING(divs, body, whatever...) but the one specified (e.g. div#special).

I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this besides the following method I can think of...

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    get mouse position x, y
    get the element (div#special in this case) position x, y
    get the element width and height
    determine if the mouse is inside the element
    if(inside)
        do nothing
    else
        do something
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: `$(':not(div#special)').bind('click', function(e) { ...` ?  http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: @JimSchubert: Should work, I'd post it as an answer - it's simpler than the answers in the possible duplicate. However, it seems inefficient.

Comment: @Wesley: But it is not correct. The event handler will also be bound to elements inside `div#special`...

Comment: @Felix: Then the selector could be `:not(div#special, div#special > *)`

Comment: @FelixKling: Good call, always glad to have your point of view.

Comment: @Jim: That is one inefficient approach. At least use `delegate` instead of `bind`.

Comment: @Jim: `:not(div#special, div#special  *)` would be correct. However I would avoid binding an event handler to *every* element. Making use of event delegation is much better in this case.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

To handle the "do this *except* when ***this*** element is clicked" situation, the general approach is to add an event handler to the `document` which handles the "do this" case, then add another event handler to the "except this" element, which simply prevents the click event bubbling up to the `document`;

```
$('#special').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
 // Do whatever you want; the event that'd fire if the "special" element has been clicked on has been cancelled.
});
```

See [the `event.stopPropagation()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). For those of you using versions earlier than jQuery 1.7 (as was the case when this question was asked), you won't be able to use `on()`; instead simple replace the 2 uses of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) with [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind); the signature in this case is the same.

Demo here; http://jsfiddle.net/HBbVC/

Comment: No offense, but that is basically the same answer as given in the duplicate I linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: @Felix: I can see that now, but you hadn't posted the comment when I started writing the reply :(.

Comment: doesn't seem to work on mobile Safari, though I don't have problems anywhere else.

Comment: Your answer, in combination with Hugo Silva's answer here fixed my particular issue on Safari. Mobile won't always allow a "click" action on non-anchors so you have to define it, it seems (see his answer for a proper explanation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers

Comment: This doesn't work if event handlers targeting other elements are defined that prevent bubbling up. This will result in those elements to be considered false positives. Imho, a better/full-proof solution is to define a document handler (as done), but define it to fire in the [capture phase](https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing), instead of bubbling phase. You'd have to actively filter in said handler which elements you want to skip/pass-through. You can omit the other handler.

Answer (score 50):

You could also do

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('#special')) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

or if div#special has child elements you could do

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).closest('#special').length === 0) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Works well when I wanted a simple solution. Thanks! - $(document).on('click', function(e) {}

Answer (score 5):

I've done it like this in the past:

```
jQuery("body").bind("click", function(e)
{
    var obj = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement);
    if (obj.tagName != 'div' && obj.id != 'special')
    {
        // Perform your click action. 
        return false;
    }
});
```

This would only execute if you didn't click on div#special. Honestly there may be better ways to do it, but this has worked for me.

Comment: You don't need to test for `e.target`. It will always be there, jQuery normalizes the event object. And it will not work if `div#special` contains other elements.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do different binds, there is no need to process all this clicks in one function

```
$('body').bind('click', function(e){
  bodyClickEvent();
});
$('div.floating').bind('click',function(e){
  elementClickEvent(this);
  e.stopPropagation(); //prevents bodyClickEvent
});
  $('div#special').bind('click', function(){
  e.stopPropagation(); //prevents bodyClickEvent
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this today for an issue i was having as i don't like having click events bound to the document the whole time, so for my scenario this works, using callbacks from functions.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        //when the notification icon is clicked open the menu
        $('#menu').slideToggle('slow', function(){
            //then bind the close event to html so it closes when you mouse off it.
            $('html').bind('click', function(e){
                $('#menu').slideToggle('slow', function(){
                    //once html has been clicked and the menu has closed, unbind the html click so nothing else has to lag up
                    $('html').unbind('click');
                });
            });
            $('#menu').bind('click', function(e){
                //as when we click inside the menu it bubbles up and closes the menu when it hits html we have to stop the propagation while its open
                e.stopPropagation();
                //once propagation has been successful! and not letting the menu open/close we can unbind this as we dont need it!
                $('#menu').unbind('click');
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your element is hovered ;)

IMHO a super simple solution that works

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  
  if($('#special:hover').length > 0){
    // on our special element
  }else{
    // not on our special element
  }
  
});
```

Cheers