# Responsive menu not working on phone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My new responsive menu does not work on pages that are not in the menu. The responsive menu works great on a small screen on the computer but not in my phone.

What's the problem?
http://www.nattklubbar.net/saddas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question has been asked before, this will give link will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722760/2012433

If this page doesn't give you a good answer, change

```
on("click", function(){...})
```

to:

```
on("click touchstart", function(){...});
```

This will bind both the click and the touchstart event.

Hope this helps :)