# jquery click event dont fires in android

Tags: android, jquery

I'm programming a Webapp using jQuery and have on the loginview a function that works like that

```
$("#login").click(function(e) {
//do stuff
});
```

On my desktop it's working, but when I test it on some friends Android phone, the button doesn't fires at all. What could be the issue? Any pointers? Already tried a few solutions from semilar threads here on stackoverflow:

[jQuery click event not working in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers)

but no success at all.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Also, what Android device and OS version) are you testing with?

Comment: Check out [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible). Try the touch events.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the input, I will try it on monday and report here

Comment: I got myself a blackberry with webkit too, and click is working, strange thing ...

Comment: Here is same question and answer, they are posted.
Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers