# Jquery mobile click event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, click

When i try to trigger an event click with a mobile browser the "click" doesn't work.
With Firefox for Desktop works fine.

This is my html:

```
<li class='brand'></li>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
$('.brand').click(function() { alert('ok') });
```

Can you explain me?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers

Comment: Use touch events like `$(document).on('touchstart', etc`

Comment: is it with in document.ready method?

Comment: Yes, It is located inside the function

Comment: `$('.brand').trigger('click');` what will happen if you put this code after event

Comment: The event is triggered multiple times (also in Mobile).
However I have more <li> with the same class.

Comment: so it shows the alert??

Comment: Yes, most times because I believe is due to the fact of having more <li> with the same class

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use touch events

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.brand', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9x9fm/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use event delegation here:

```
$(document).on('click', '.brand', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: No, you need to put inside

Comment: It does not work, maybe the problem is somewhere else?
Firefox Desktop works correctly both ways

Answer (score 1):

```
Try to use like this:

$('.brand').on('click' function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```