# jQuery click event not working in mobile Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, mobile, samsung-mobile

I have a navigation menu that shows and hides on mobile devices when an element is clicked.  It works everywhere except in Firefox on Samsung Galaxy 3. Here's the HTML:

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
  Etc . .
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div id="nav-arrow">&#9660;</div>
```

The element with the click event attached is "nav-arrow". Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#nav-arrow").click(function() {
        if ($("#nav").is(":visible")) {
            $("#nav").slideUp(800, function() {
                $("#nav-arrow").html("&#9660;");
            }); 
        } else {
            $("#nav").slideDown(800, function() {
                $("#nav-arrow").html("&#9650;");
            });             
        }
    });
```

The  container is has a property of display:none until the nav-arrow is clicked. Can anyone help me get this working on Mobile Firefox?

Comment: I'm really not sure if what you are trying to do is possible. It should be, but I'm not entirely convinced that jquery has the necessary foundation to be handling clicks on mobile. I think what you want to do is use jquery-mobile and it's vclick event.

Comment: This is working on every mobile device and browser except for Firefox on Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: See what using .on('click', function ... will do instead of just .click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776570/jquery-mobile-click-event-doesnt-work

This I think is your problem?

Comment: Using .on('click', had the same results. I ended up solving this problem by downloading just the touch events from the jQuery Mobile Download Builder and switching the click function to .on('tap', function . . . etc. That was the cure.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile requires the "delegate" method:

```js
$(document).delegate('#nav-arrow', 'click', function () {
    if ($("#nav").is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#nav").slideUp(800, function()
        {
            $("#nav-arrow").html("&#9660;");
        }); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#nav").slideDown(800, function()
        {
            $("#nav-arrow").html("&#9650;");
        });
    }    
});
```