# jQuerys click and tap events not working on FF mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

in my project I am using jQuery and jQuery mobile.
When I tap on the menuOpener, the menu should open. This works fine on desktop and Chrome mobile.
But not in Firefox mobile.
I couldn't test it in Safari mobile.

I have already tried all the suggestion I have found in SO and else.
Irritatingly an old project, which has worked fine, so far, now is showing the same behaviour.

My HTML:

```
<div id="menuOpener">
  <div class="hamburger hamburger1"></div>
  <div class="hamburger hamburger2"></div>
  <div class="hamburger hamburger3"></div>
</div>

<div id="menu">
  <!-- some menu elements here -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#menuOpener').on('click tap', function(){
  alert ( 'open' );
  $('#menu').toggleClass('open');
  $(this).toggleClass('open');  
});
```

The problem appears on this subpage, which I am using for testing [Link](http://www.vhs-glueckstadt.de/basteln/)

I hope, someone has an idea, why this is happening.

Regards
Christian

Comment: These are the topics, I have already gone through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776570/jquery-mobile-click-event-doesnt-work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device

Comment: works fine in FF desktop/mobile.

Comment: Just found more strangeness: FF on my girlsfriends mobile works fine, too. So it has to be an issue with my specific FF.

Comment: Have you tried binding also 'vclick' event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting mad about this: 
Reinstalled Firefox, works perfectly now.