# How can i fire jQuery .click() or .tap() event on mobile devices explicitly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, tap, jquery-events

I am firing a click event on a div by click() function of jquery. It is working good in desktop browser, but in mobile devices it is not working.

I found that click event doesn't supported by mobile browsers, i tried tap event by trigger("tap"), but it is also not working.

I need to tap or click event in mobile devices by jquery/javascript, how can i do this ?

Comment: this looks a lot like this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers

Comment: Why would you need to trigger these events?

Comment: I need to trigger this event because there is a plugin i have which shows details information of the division which was i clicked. So i need to show that information by default when he comes up to the website.

Answer (score 2):

Click events should work on mobile. Sometimes you need to add

```
cursor: pointer
```

to the clickable elements.

Comment: Means i have to add a style to that element ?

Comment: Yes, but this is just for iOS devices. By default elements (except for a tags) are not clickable on iPhones/iPads.