# Meteor Jquery Click Events Not Registering On Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, meteor

I current have a Meteor 1.2.1 project that I'm developing and for some reason click/touch events are not being registered on mobile devices.  Everything is working fine locally in both the browser (using mobile/desktop views) and the ios simulator when I run `meteor run ios`.  I've created a few mobile-friendly apps using Meteor before and I've never had a problem.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the new Meteor 1.2 version.

Also, these are inside my main.html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

**Update-**

Seems as though the click events function once I add in a front-end framework such as Foundation or Bootstrap.  Still makes me wonder what those packages do to enable clicking on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a little more research I realized this is not related to Meteor, but rather to jQuery.  Seems as though there are problems with mobile browsers registering click events on divs, so I just changed everything to an `<a>` tag instead.

Link to the stackoverflow question [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers).

Comment: Thanks for spotting.

Comment: another trick is to add css property: `cursor: pointer;` to any non `a, button` elements you want to make it clickable ;)