# jQuery click alternative for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery `click` event for toggling my navigation bar. The code I am using is something like this:

```
$('.nav-button').on('click', function () {

    $('.navigation, .nav-button').toggleClass('show-nav');

});
```

Where `.nav-button` is a `div`. Everything is fine in Android version of Chrome, but Firefox Android is not doing anything on touching the `<div class="nav-button"></div>`

Is there any solution, or alternative for jQuery `click` event for touch devices?

Comment: take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device) ;-)

Comment: @Chris thanks this one worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$('.nav-button').on('click touchstart', function () {

    $('.navigation, .nav-button').toggleClass('show-nav');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Which jQuery are you using? I recommend using the jQuery Mobile library.
Its almost the same as the jQuery . They have events that are specific to touch devices in jQuery Mobile.

eg

```html
$("p").on("tap",function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```js
$("p").on("taphold",function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```js
$("p").on("swipeleft",function(){
  alert("You swiped left!");
});
```

Comment: Do I have to install jQuery mobile separately with normal jQuery?

Comment: You can put a second link to the jQuery Mobile file in your html file

Answer (score 0):

I found another thread on this topic on stackoverflow: [jQuery click event not working in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers)

As my previous speaker mentioned you could try it with jQuery Mobile. There is something similiar to the click event handler which is called `vclick` in jQuery Mobile:

Here a small example how it looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-button').vclick(function() {
        $('.navigation, .nav-button').toggleClass('show-nav');
    });
});
```