# Jquery on click doesn't work on Firefox Android

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery 3.1.1. My code works fine on desktop and Chrome Android, but doesn't work at Firefox Android.

```
 $('.menu').on('click', function() {
     $('.aside').addClass('slide-in');
 });
```

Making `'click touchstart'` doesn't help, even causes more problems as on Crhome it makes two "touches" instead of one

Comment: @DBS - as I have mentioned, **Making 'click touchstart' doesn't help (doesn't work in Firefox)**, and in Chrome there is a clickable element behind it

Comment: I would cover all my bases. Do an ".on('click active focus'". Also, be sure that there is an 'event.preventDefault()' depending on the html.

Comment: @Doe Fair enough, I misread that using `touchstart` worked _because_ of the chrome problems, not _as well as_. Have you tried the various answers in posts like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers