# Click body but not two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my function:

`document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click',e=>{getRandomImagePair()});`

When I click anywhere on the body something happens. I have two `div`s `.more` and `.wd` and if I click on them the function `getRandomImagePair()` executes. How can I make so that if I click the links the function doesn't fire?

I tried this below, it works but then the `.more` div won't trigger another needed different function.

```
$('.more, .wd').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Well does the function get triggered on click?

Comment: @epascarello yes on clicking the body but also the two divs. One div triggers another function also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery bind click \*ANYTHING\* but \*ELEMENT\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635659/jquery-bind-click-anything-but-element)

Comment: You can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/pe9yt467/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation), just check the `className` of the `event.target` element. Use an `if` statement in your event handler callback to prevent `getRandomImagePair` from being called a link was clicked on:

```js
function getRandomImagePair() {
  console.log('getRandomImagePair called');
}

//using event delegation
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.className !== 'wd' && e.target.className !== 'more') {
    getRandomImagePair();
  }
});
```

```css
.wd,
.more {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="more">.more</div>
  <div class="wd">.wd</div>

  <p>Here is some other stuff</p>
  <p>that when clicked on should still fire event handler</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This has a flaw if there are children inside of the element `<div class="more"><span>click here</span>.more</div>` So if OP has nested elements inside, than this answer will fail.

Comment: @epascarello Nothing about nested `<span>` elements was detailed in the question.

Comment: I agree this answer will work if there is no nesting. Just stating it in case the OP has it since it is vary rare the OP shows the actual HTML. Using [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) would be safer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the items you don't want to be affected by the click :

```js
const getRandomImagePair = () => {
 alert("clicked")
}

$('body :not(".more, .wd")').on('click', getRandomImagePair);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Yep</button>
<button class="more">Nope</button>
<button class="wd">Nope</button>
<button>Yep</button>
```

Comment: This is different though, I need that document.querySelector and it doesn't work with 'body :not(".more, .wd")'

Comment: Why do you _need_ document.querySelector? And why did you try with jQuery and added the jQuery tag, then?

Comment: @Federico this is equivalent of `document.querySelector('body :not(.more):not(.wd)')`

Comment: Has an issue.... `<button class="more"><span>Nope</span></button>` so if the OP has a nested element, it will not work.